# empty tableview rows when parsing with NSXMLPaerser using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, asihttprequest, nsxmlparser

I'm pretty new iPhone development and i have a problem.
After several hours of searching and digging in the code I could understand the source of the problem (hope) but do not know how to solve it.
the problem is that the tableView cells loads before the parser is finish so the "[array count]" is nil.
When I set the 'number of rows in section' manually, the table does appear, but only after a few sec and scrolling up and down.

i have 2 classes, one for XMLParser and one for show the tableView.
According to what I read before I opened this question is that i need to reload the tavleview data but becuase i have 2 various classes i dont know how to do that.
any ideas?

Thanks in davance!

**here is my XMLParser code:**

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{ 
    self.titles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.descriptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.links = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.pubDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{

}

BOOL isItem = NO;
BOOL isTitle = NO;
BOOL isDesription = NO;
BOOL isImg = NO;
BOOL isPubDate = NO;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        isItem = YES;
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        isTitle=YES;
        self.titlesString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        isDesription = YES;
        self.descriptionString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];;
        self.data = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        isPubDate = YES;
        self.pubDateString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if(isItem && isTitle){
        [self.titlesString appendString:string];
    }
    if (isItem && isDesription) {
        [self.descriptionString appendString:string];
    }
    if (isItem && isPubDate) {
        [self.pubDateString appendString:string];
    }


}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
    if (self.data)
        [self.data appendData:CDATABlock];

}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{



    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        isItem = NO;



        [self.titles addObject:self.titlesString];
        [self.descriptions addObject:self.descriptionString];
        [self.pubDate addObject:self.pubDateString];
        NSLog(@"%@,%@,%@,",self.titlesString,self.descriptionString,self.pubDate);

    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        isTitle=NO;

    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        isDesription = NO;


        if ([self.data length] > 0)
        {
            NSString *htmlSnippet = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSString *imageSrc = [self firstImgUrlString:htmlSnippet];
            [self.links addObject:imageSrc];
        }

        self.data = nil;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"pubDate"])
        isPubDate = NO;
}

- (NSString *)firstImgUrlString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img\\s[\\s\\S]*?src\\s*?=\\s*?['\"](.*?)['\"][\\s\\S]*?>)+?"
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];

    NSTextCheckingResult *result = [regex firstMatchInString:string
                                                     options:0
                                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    if (result)
        return [string substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:2]];

    return nil;

}
```

**and here's my show tableView code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

       self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuButton.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self.viewDeckController action:@selector(toggleLeftView)];

    NSURL *url;

    if (!self.isGetLink)
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ynet.co.il/Integration/StoryRss2.xml"];
    else
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.linkForParsingString];


    if (!self.xmlParser) {
        self.xmlParser = [[XMLparser alloc]init];

        [self.xmlParser LoadXMLWithURl:url];
    }

    self.isGetLink = NO;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
{

}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.xmlParser.titles count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    cell.lblTitle.text = [self.xmlParser.titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.xmlParser.links objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    cell.imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];


    return cell;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 82;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate
NSString *curnentDes;
NSString *currentTitle;
NSString *currentPubDate;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ReadViewController *rvc = [[ReadViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ReadViewController" bundle:nil];
    curnentDes = [self.xmlParser.descriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    currentTitle = [self.xmlParser.titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    currentPubDate = [self.xmlParser.pubDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

    [inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *inputDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:currentPubDate];
    NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
    NSString *outputDate = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:inputDate];

    rvc.description = curnentDes;
    rvc.stitle = currentTitle;
    rvc.pubDate = outputDate;


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple reload the table after your parsing is done, you are good to go. The reason your data comes after scrolling is your array is updated at a later point and then cellForRowAtIndex is called and array has content so you see rows.

Note: cellForRow is called for every row (hope you know that).

Using notification:

In your parser class

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{ 
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ]postNotificationName:@"parsingComplete" object:nil];
}
```

In ViewDidLoad of your table view class add this code and add the other functions anywhere in ur class:

your viewDidLoad(edited)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(parsingComplete) name:@"parsingComplete" object:nil];
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuButton.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self.viewDeckController action:@selector(toggleLeftView)];

NSURL *url;

if (!self.isGetLink)
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ynet.co.il/Integration/StoryRss2.xml"];
else
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.linkForParsingString];


if (!self.xmlParser) {
    self.xmlParser = [[XMLparser alloc]init];

    [self.xmlParser LoadXMLWithURl:url];
}

self.isGetLink = NO;
}
```

//Function to handle notification:

```
-(void)parsingComplete
 {
  NSLog(@"parsing results: %@",self.xmlParser.titles); 

  //change your tableViewName

  [yourTableView reloadData];
 }
```

//removing notification:

```
 -(void)dealloc
 {
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response..
but could you explain how and where should i reload the data?
my in - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser?
if it is, how? as i said i have 2 various classes.. i cant call for reload tableview from the xmlparser class..

Comment: You can use delegation or notification. Which one you want to try?.

Comment: I will do notification first.

Comment: omg i dont really know what to do.. can you write my a sample or something?
im just pretty new to ios development.
i would be greatful if you could..

Comment: @ OshriALM Have u tried by reload the table view after the parsing completed as satheeshwaran said?

Comment: The thing is that if I do not set the "NumberOfRowsInSection" manually the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" methos is not called because the [myArray count] which i returned in "NumberOfRowsInSection" methos is nil..
so i need to reaload the tableview somewhere after the parser is done!

Comment: What? Can u post what you tried? Keep a break point in the notification function and check whether it is being called.

Comment: yes, the method is called after the parser is done.
but now i see a white screen instead of table view :/

Comment: \U05d1\U05d3\U05de\U05e9\U05e7 \U05d0\U05ea \U05d4\U05de\U05d5\U05e8\U05d3\U05d9\U05dd: '\U05d1\U05d5\U05e0\U05d4 \U05de\U05e0\U05d4\U05e8\U05d5\U05ea'",
    "\U05d7\U05e9\U05d3: \U05d1\U05df 15 \U05e0\U05e4\U05dc

Comment: Can you post the -(void)parsingComplete functions code in your project?

Comment: -(void)parsingComplete
{
    NSLog(@"parsing results: %@",self.xmlParser.titles);
    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

Comment: not working.. and the ui stuck.
i think the [array count] is still nil and the view loaded before its get any object in him..
can you take one more look at the code? maybe youll find somthing..
or shuld we try the "delegate" way?

Comment: Man the array is getting updated that's why you got some stuff in NSLog, I guess some problem in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Does cellForRow, Number of rows methods are called, after tableView reloadData?

Comment: I guess problem with this statement -  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.xmlParser.links objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    cell.imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; Try commenting the line and try.

Comment: ok i fixed it..
i had [tableview reload] at the cellforrowatindexpath too.
but now i have another problem, when the app is up the first screen show but if i press on another one (i have slide menu) i get EXC_BAD_ACCSESS and the tableView do not appear.

Comment: Never call tableView reloadData in cellForRowAtIndex it will create a infinite loop. Give me crash log.

Comment: malloc: *** error for object 0x6bc82f0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Answer (score 0):

Reload the table once parsing is completed. Use delegate methods to reload the table view from   didEndElement method. Try some think like this.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Final Element"])
    {

     // Reload your table View using delegates 

    }
}
```

Comment: what you mean when you say "using delegates"?

Comment: delegates are used to communicate or delegate actions from a delegate firing entity and a receiving entity to do a particular action. NSNotification is pretty simple but delegation is a better way if there is only one receiver, if multiple go for notifications.

Comment: @OshriALM  satheeshwaran answer have fix for your query. Just try NSNotification its more simple to understand than delegate.